# Concatenate in C# Repository

Tags: c#, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate the value of scoreField but I'm getting null value.  Here's my code:

```
public List<PlainBrgMetric> GetPlainBrgMetricForSortBy(long programID)
{
    return _context.metrics
          .Where(m => m.programLOBID == programID)
          .Select(m => new PlainBrgMetric
          {
              label = m.label,
              scoreField = "s" + m.metrictNumber
          }).ToList();
}

public int? metrictNumber { get; set; }       
public string scoreField { get; set; }
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Which line is giving the null reference exception?

Comment: I'm getting null value.

Comment: scoreField = "s" + m.metrictNumber

Answer (score 2):

If metricNumber is null... you will get null... try

```
scorefield = "s" + m.metricNumber?? "";
```

or another way to write it is

```
scorefield= "s" + (m.metricNumber == null? "" : m.metricNumber);
```

Now, when metric number is null, you will just get "s"

Comment: `"a" + (int?)null` gives `"a"` in Linqpad, not `null`

Comment: but if the context actually decides to get the value via the sql select statement, it would be sql null plus a letter, which in most sql server systems will be null (null concat yields null setting). He's using Repo pattern he said in title, so I assume it's coming from EF/database